# Metodo asincrono javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Supongamos que tengo el metodo test() que tarda 1 min en finalizar.

```
$('#myModalLoading').modal('show');

//Este método tarda 1 minuto
$scope.test = test()

//Mientars tanto me gustaria que se ejecutara estos otros métodos pero el navegador no lo ejecuara hasta que termine el anterior

$scope.test2 = test2()
$scope.test3 = test3()
```

El problema es que hasta que no se ejecte el método test no se ejecutan los otros 2. ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Qué hace la función test? Dependiendo de su naturaleza podrás hacer lo que intentas o no

Comment: la funcion test hace un calculo en javascript, no hace una llamada REST.

Comment: Javascript ejecuta todo en un único hilo. La única solución sería usar webworkers o intentar "trocear" la ejecución de ese cálculo para evitar congelar la UI

Comment: si sacara una especie de modal que se actualice evitaria congelar el navegador, he pnesado en un setInterval pero no consigo que se refresque. No es posible trocearlo

Answer (score 0):

Tu ejemplo no es muy adecuado, ya que no presenta exactamente asincronismo, pero creo entender el problema, yo lo que haria seria lo siguiente:

```js
window.onload = ()=> {

  $scope = window;

  $scope.test = async()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("Test uno terminado!");
    }, 5000)
  }
  
  $scope.test2 = ()=>{
    console.log("Realizando el segundo test... mientras el primero termina...");
  }
  
  $scope.test3 = ()=>{
    console.log("Realizando el tercer test... mientras el primero termina...");
  }
  
  test();
  test2();
  test3();

}
```

Porsupuesto estoy haciendo una simulación de asincronismo usando un `setTimeout` pero es aplicable a tu caso, pues enrealidad podemos ver como mientras se va a ejecutando el primer proceso (`test`) los otros dos se ejecutan mientras tanto sin bloquear tu codigo como lo habias pensado.

De hecho teoricamente sin tener que hacer la funcion `test` asincrona esto deberia funcionar, asi que lo mas probable es que si tu codigo se bloquea es porque tu codigo termina siendo bloqueante, siendo que al haber un problema con tu codigo se genera un `Error` y no una `Exception`.

Que recordemos que la principal diferencia entre un `Error` y un `Exception` es que el `Error` termina la ejecucion del código e imprime el error, mientras que la `Exception` no termina la ejecución del código, pero imprime el error.

Por ende otra posibilidad es que enrealidad no es que el codigo se este bloqueando, si no que en algun momento se genera un error terrible en el codigo que no permita que las demas instrucciones se lleven a cabo:

```js
window.onload = ()=> {

  $scope = window;

  $scope.test = async()=>{
    //Suponiendo que se genero un error
    throw new Error("Something went wrong doing the first process!");
    
    //Esto ya no se ejecuta
    test2();
    test3();
  }
  
  $scope.test2 = ()=>{
    console.log("Realizando el segundo test... mientras el primero termina...");
  }
  
  $scope.test3 = ()=>{
    console.log("Realizando el tercer test... mientras el primero termina...");
  }
  
  test().catch(e =>{
    console.log(e.message);
  });

}
```

La otra posible opcion que hay es que dices que el metodo test se encarga de hacer unos calculos, los calculos sencillos normalmente no demoran mas de unas cuantas milesimas de segundo en `JS`.

Asi que asumo que son operaciones complejas y con bucles que tardan rato en resolverse...

Pero y si sin querer estas cayendo en un bucle infinito en alguna condicion de tu calculo y quiza esto es lo que te bloquea?

```
let dividirACero = 5;

while(dividirACero %= 4 != 0){
   console.log("BUCLE INFINITO!");
}
```

Y si... se que en tu etiqueta estas usando `angular` pero estos ejemplos son perfectamente adaptables a `angular`.

Esto es todo lo que se me ocurre que puede estar pasando por el momento.